# map `ctrl +` to tabn

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to map `CTRL-+` to `:tabn`. But it does not work.

```
inoremap <C-+> :tabn<CR>
inoremap <C--> :tabp<CR>
nnoremap <C-+> :tabn<CR>
nnoremap <C--> :tabp<CR>
```

It does not work in insert mode also not in normal mode.

If I try the following (without `CTRL`), then it works, but then I can't switch tabs when I am in insert mode:

```
nnoremap + :tabn<CR>
nnoremap - :tabp<CR>
```

How can I map `CTRL-+` to `:tabn` so I can switch tabs when in insert mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

For me (in English Windows GVIM), it *is* possible to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> as `<C-_>`, though.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8)

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Answer (score 1):

Only a few control-printable key chords can be detected (and therefore mapped) by Vim, and these are listed in the [FAQ](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5). Unfortunately `<CTRL-+>` and `<CTRL-->` are not mentioned in this list, so it looks like such mappings are impossible.

There is on-going [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/Ym6D-kWIsyo/-XOw7E8LbN0J) about whether to redesign Vim's key model, but this probably have to wait until Vim 8.0. I am not optimistic.